# Start "iex" with loading app, and run command in 1 line

Tags: elixir

I want to do auto build like "gulp.js" in Node.js.

> $ iex -S mix -e 'DribbbleGif.main'
>
> ** (Mix) Cannot implicitly pass flags to default mix task, please invoke instead: mix run

I want to do this in 1 line command.

1. load app
2. start "iex"
3. do function (DribbbleGif.main)

---

Because, finally I want to watch file like this.

> chokidar **/*.exs **/*.ex -c 'iex -S mix -e 'DribbbleGif.main''

---

If you have other solution for auto build, please tell me it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try:

```
iex -S mix run -e "DribbbleGif.main"
```